# jQuery Counter Function not working in IE < 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a simple piece of code which I'm running to increment a counter by 1 repeatedly until it reaches a certain amount.

The code operates fine on Chrome/FF/IE9+ but on IE7/8 it gets to £1.80 and stops running.

I can't seem to find the breaking point of it, but it's obviously running a certain amount of times and then stopping.

The main function is:

```
        (function($) {
            $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
                options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});
                var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refresh_interval),
                    increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;
                return $(this).each(function() {
                    var _this = this,
                        loop_count = 0,
                        value = options.from,
                        interval = setInterval(update_timer, options.refresh_interval);
                    function update_timer() {
                        value += increment;
                        loop_count++;
                        if(options.format == 'money') {
                            $(_this).html('\u00A3' + number_with_commas(value.toFixed(options.decimals)));
                        } else {
                            $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));
                        }
                        if(typeof(options.on_update) == 'function') {
                            options.on_update.call(_this, value);
                        }
                        if(loop_count >= loops) {
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            value = options.to;
                            if(typeof(options.on_complete) == 'function') {
                                options.on_complete.call(_this, value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
            $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
                from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
                to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
                speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
                refresh_interval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
                decimals: 2,  // the number of decimal places to show
                on_update: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
                on_complete: null  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
            };
        })(jQuery);
```

Example is: http://jsfiddle.net/yxEaN/

Thanks.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - no console errors

Comment: Could it be one of your callbacks that's failing?

Comment: If only jsFiddle worked in >IE8 we could test, but as I don't, and jQuery has even dropped support in some of the newer versions, why do you care ?

Comment: @cfs - callbacks are both null in this case.

Comment: @adeneo - IE7+ is still something I need to support. I'm used to working for some large corporations which have IE7/IE8 rolled out across all of their dealerships/offices, so in cases like that it has to be supported.

Comment: @adeneo could still use the show page of jsfiddle just to test  http://jsfiddle.net/yxEaN/show  and yes, as OP, cannot see any error

Comment: looks like the speed is causing issue: http://jsfiddle.net/YMQQw/show/

Comment: @roasted - The speed seems to have something to do with it, but the longer you set the speed to the less it increments. Your example with a 2500 speed stops running at £0.02, and if its set to 5000 it stops at £0.01

Comment: @God have you check my answer?

Comment: @ripa it works in IE, just not exactly how I need it to due to the refresh interval, but it seems IE can't handle a very quick refresh interval. I'll mark as answer anyway as it does allow it to run in IE, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has solved for IE. Check my below code

```
function number_with_commas(x) {
return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

$.ajaxSetup ({
   // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
   cache: false
});

(function($) 
{
$.fn.countTo = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});
    var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refresh_interval),
        increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;
    return $(this).each(function() {
        var _this = this,
            loop_count = 0,
            value = options.from,
            interval = setInterval(function(){
                value += increment;
                loop_count++;
                if(options.format == 'money') {
                    $(_this).html('\u00A3' + number_with_commas(value.toFixed(options.decimals)));
                } else {
                    $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));
                }
                if(typeof(options.on_update) == 'function') {
                    options.on_update.call(_this, value);
                }
                if(loop_count >= loops) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    value = options.to;
                    if(typeof(options.on_complete) == 'function') {
                        options.on_complete.call(_this, value);
                    }
                }

                },100);

    });
};

$.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0,
    to: 100,
    speed: 1000,
    refresh_interval: 100,
    decimals: 2,
    on_update: null,
    on_complete: null
};
})(jQuery);

$(function($) {
    $('#total_charity_counter').countTo({
    format: 'money',
    from: 0,
    to: 4229.01,
    speed: (4229.01 / 180),
    refresh_interval: .01,
    on_complete: function(value) {
    $(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);
}
    });
});
```